# How to migrate from javascumbs to springframework-ws-test

Tags: java, spring-ws

We are using old technology to testing our webservices (javascumbs). Is there some tutorial how I can migrate this to springframework-ws-test ?

Now my test look like:

```
@Test
public void testWs() throws Exception {
    MessageContext message = helper.receiveMessage("xml/file.xml");
    WebServiceMessage response = message.getResponse();
    MessageValidator validator = helper.createMessageValidator(response);
    validator.assertNotSoapFault();
    validator.assertSoapMessage();
    validator.validate("xsd/xsd1.xsd", "xsd/xsd2.xsd");
    validator.compare("xml/response.ftl");
}
```

I found some tutorial [here](http://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-client-side-integration-testing/). But it look totally different. I am loading xml from file which also contains envelop and header and in this example there is just request

Comment: why downvote ? What is wrong about tutorial from some old version of technology to new one ?

Comment: CXF-based approach: https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf

Answer (score 1):

I would say, give your tests full environment using docker. It will enable you to do other types of testing and will help you to evolve projects CI/CD. One of the tutorial for the same is http://blog.arungupta.me/run-javaee-tests-wildfly-docker-arquillian-cube/. FYI, this is just starting point. We are using this combination to test more than 100 git repositories in our product line.